# how to get month end data from daily data using formula

Tags: google-sheets

how to get month end data from daily data using formula

I have used some formula, but instead of last trading day it shows first Day data of the month

```
=ARRAYFORMULA((QUERY(SORTN(TEXT(GOOGLEFINANCE(A2,"Price",TODAY()-3000, TODAY(),"Daily"),{"yyyy mm","@"}),9^9,2,1,0),"Select * order by Col1 DESC limit 40 label Col2 '' ")))
```

This formula get first day data of every month

How to get last trading data of the months??

Comment: Expert Please Help Me to solve above Formula